# Redis cluster performance - high timeout rate on low load

Tags: performance, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

See strange behavior of redis cluster, which works totally fine on big load and starts to run with 50% timeout rate and unstable response times on low load.

We have same patter each day on periods of low load.

Any ideas what could cause such a strange pattern? Maybe some maintenance work this RedisCluster starts to do on low load time? Like slots rebalancing. Please recommend any settings or aspects to check.

Versions: Redis 2.0.7, Jedis 2.8.1

Configuration: 3 physical nodes with 9 master processes and 18 slaves.

JedisCluster Timeout = 5ms.

Load is 100% writes with setex.

[image: JedisCluster response time]
[image: JedisCluster timeout rate]

This graphs are for JedisCluster response times, not actual RedisCluster times.
"Sets" line here is successful sets actually, not total count.

Comment: do you have dns lookups when connecting to RedisCluster?

Comment: @Slach no, we connect by ip and use connection pool via Jedis, so reconnection is rare situation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found that it looks like network issue.

```
redis08(10.201.12.214) ~ $ redis-benchmark -h 10.201.12.215 -p 9006
====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 91.42 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 11 milliseconds

redis09(10.201.12.215) ~ $ redis-benchmark -h 10.201.12.215 -p 9006
====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.41 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

99.46% <= 1 milliseconds

redis08 ~ $ ping lga-redis09
PING redis09 (10.201.12.215) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from redis09 (10.201.12.215): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.7 ms
```

Looking at collectd's "if_octets" we have enormous network activity on network interfaces on this time of low write activity. Nighttime load is like 10x in comparison with daytime load.

And it is caused by redis nodes which start to actively exchange information on this low load period.
Iptraf top connections output:
[image: Iptraf output, most packets and traffic are between redis nodes/processes itself]
While on daytime top in this iptraf report belongs fully to actual redis clients with good write load.

Finally found that we have issues with replication. Sometimes buffer was not enough and slaves started full resync. Looks like this night load - full resync attempts + low repl-timeout value - neverending replication attempts as a result. Why this replication affects low night load so significantly and didn't affect day time - I don't know, see no options that make redis do more often attempts  on nights or something like that.
If it's interesting, we fixed neverending replication by increasing obvious settings:

```
repl-backlog-size
repl-timeout
```